# Найти пересечение луча, пущенного из центра камеры с плоскостью в пространстве Android ArCore

Tags: android, ar, arcore

Коллеги, возникла необходимость найти пересечение луча, пущенного из центра камеры с плоскостью образованной от Plane.

[image: Plane]

1) Я могу находить результаты

```
HitResult Frame frame = arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame();
List<HitResult> hitResults = frame.hitTest(screenCenterX, screenCenterY);
if (hitResults != null && hitResults.size() > 0) {
    HitResult hitResult = hitResults.get(0);
    Pose pose = hitResult.getHitPose();
    Vector3 position = new Vector3(pose.tx(), pose.ty(), pose.tz());
}
```

но это не подходит к решаемой задаче, так как не всегда возвращается результат (не в каждом кадре и в случае потери плана).

2) Я могу хранить данные по найденному плану и мне необходимо в каждый конкретный момент времени знать точную позицию на плане, на которую направлена камера.

Я понимаю, что в данном случае мне может помочь объект Ray, но не понимаю, какую вторую точку ему указать. Я пробовал делать так:

```
Camera camera = arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().getCamera();
Ray ray = new Ray(camera.getWorldPosition(), camera.getForward());
HitTestResult result = arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().hitTest(ray);
Vector3 vector3 = result.getPoint();
```

Но полученный ответ не корректный - точка ответа всегда имеет координаты `Log Ray result vector3 [x=0.0, y=0.0, z=0.0]`

Как правильно найти пересечение луча, пущенного из центра камеры с плоскостью в пространстве ArCore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения проблемы я решил использовать добавление условно-бесконечной фигуры в виде тонкой плоскости. В таком случае `hitTest(ray)` будет возвращать точные координаты пересечения луча и данной плоскости.

Для этого я делаю такие действия:
1. Подготовить модель фигуры которая будет работать:

```
private Color colorGreen = new Color(android.graphics.Color.GREEN);

private void makeInfinityModel() {
        MaterialFactory.makeTransparentWithColor(getApplicationContext(), colorGreen)
                .thenAccept(material -> {
                    ModelRenderable model = ShapeFactory.makeCube(
                            new Vector3(500000f, 0.0001f, 500000f),
                            Vector3.zero(), material);
                    model.setShadowCaster(false);
                    model.setShadowReceiver(false);
                    model.setRenderPriority(0);
                    mInfinityModel = model;
                });
    }
```

2. Добавляем нашей сцене слушатель обновлений:
   `mArFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addOnUpdateListener(this::sceneHasBeenUpdated);`
3. `private void sceneHasBeenUpdated(FrameTime frameTime) {
           // enable an infinity node
           addInfinityNode();`

   ```
       // hit
       Camera camera = mArFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().getCamera();
       Ray ray = new Ray(camera.getLocalPosition(), camera.getForward());
       HitTestResult result = mArFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().hitTest(ray);
       Vector3 resultPosition = result.getPoint();

       // disable an infinity node
       removeInfinityNode();

       if (result.getNode() != null) {
           // do something with resultPosition
       }
   }
   ```

4.

```
private void addInfinityNode() {
        Pose anchorPose = mCurrentPlaneAnchor.getPose();
        Vector3 position = new Vector3(anchorPose.tx(), anchorPose.ty(), anchorPose.tz());
        if (mInfinityModel == null) {
            return;
        }
        AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode();
        anchorNode.setParent(mArFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
        Node node = new Node();
        node.setParent(anchorNode);
        node.setRenderable(mInfinityModel);
        node.setLight(null);
        node.setLocalPosition(position.scaled(1f));
        mInfinityAnchorNode = anchorNode;
    }
```

5.

```
private void removeInfinityNode() {
        try {
            if (mInfinityAnchorNode != null) {
                if (mInfinityAnchorNode.getAnchor() != null) {
                    mInfinityAnchorNode.getAnchor().detach();
                }
                mInfinityAnchorNode.setParent(null);
                mInfinityAnchorNode = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // do nothing for the Exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Таким образом, при получении нового кадра система включает модельку, ищет пересечение с лучом, получает координаты и выключает модельку. Вот и всё. Happy coding!

Примечание:
результат работы
[image: результат работы]